# How can I activate UFW on my Raspberry Pi 3 B without risking to lock myself out?

Tags: iptables

I want to activate UFW on my Raspberry Pi 3 B as I have used it previously on another machine and was quite content with that software.

I have already downloaded UFW but I need to make sure that I don't lock myself out when I enable it.

I am remote controlling the Raspberry Pi 3 B over USB and VPN using USB tethering. A rather unusual setup. So please bear that in mind if replying in this thread.

Also, if I do get locked out, would it be possible to just remove some files from the SD card to prevent UFW from starting if I reboot?

Comment: how about just backing up the whole sd card and revert if something goes wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have a cron job that disables ufw every 10 / 20 minutes so if you do lock yourself out you can make a coffee, put your feet up and reflect on what you did wrong.

Remember to remove the cron job and enable ufw when you are done :-)

You can test the cron job by enabling ufw with allow all as default rules...

Answer (score 1):

You can install and start ufw for testing without enabling the service. If you make a mistake, reboot. Also, IIRC, it won't bump out an *established* session. Open a window to install and configure, the *leave this window open with the login session active* while you open another and connect to test. Avoid the compulsion to close every session as you go and you should be fine.

Comment: How can I start the ufw service without enabling it? There is no UFW start command in the manual as far as I can tell.